# Change domain of hyper-v manager server

Tags: domain, hyper-v

I have hyper-v manager running on my machine. I am logged in on this with as administrator@domain.com

I had to build a new domain with a dc that is in hyper-v. The current machine where hyper-v manager is on, it still in the old domain( that does nog excists anymore).

Can I somehow change that without losing all my VM's?

Answer (score 2):

The virtual machines aren't bound to your Hyper-V management console, they're bound to the Hyper-V host. Changing the domain membership of the computer that you're running the Hyper-V Manager from won't have any effect on your virtual machines.